# BeautifulSoup not handling HTML table inside anchor tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Consider the sample HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

On using BeautifulSoup on this via:
`html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source_code,"lxml")`
I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
    </a>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Note how the table is no longer contained within the anchor tag, thereby altering the output.

I have run the source code through online validators (e.g. https://validator.w3.org/) and they return no errors or warning, and so I believe there is nothing wrong with the HTML code itself.

Why does BS cause this error, and how can I fix it?
p.s. Not trivial for me (in my real use case) to move the  tags to inner  elements owing to pre-defined and CSS and JS features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"html.parser"`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_source_code = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </a>
</body>
</html>"""

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source_code,"html.parser")
print(html_soup.prettify(formatter='html'))
```

**Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>
   Testing
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a href="https://www.google.com">
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>
      Hello
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </a>
 </body>
</html>
```